# Pass the Get Value in Flow

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, power-automate

I am creating a flow where i get a id value of user using.

Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
When i run the flow i can see the object id of user is there. I want to pass this value to below in {id}

Delete [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/6b01ca36-8aa9-4f24-95bb-3fd60d33fdee/members/{id}/$ref](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/6b01ca36-8aa9-4f24-95bb-3fd60d33fdee/members/%7Bid%7D/$ref).

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were already able to call graph from flow. what returns should be a JSON, so what you need to do is run it through Parse JSON action, then you should be able to loop through the resulting output and make another HTTP call to graph with that parameter substituted in the URL string as a "dynamic content"